# Where does User Login Logic Belong? 3-Tier Application

Tags: c#, .net, security, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I was wondering where user login logic resides in a typical application. In my current App, it seems that the best place would be the UI layer. So if the business layer is ever ported to a new platform (desktop-WPF to webpage for example) the respective platforms would handle their own security. This also seems to follow inline with responsibility principles. For example, my business layer doesn't care if a user is logged in, it only cares that a component has requested a piece of processed data. Likewise my UI layer definitely cares if a user is logged in because it has to know what controls or actions to make visible.

The problem is, logging a user in requires access to the data layer. which the UI layer obviously doesn't have.

If I put the user login component in a shared "common" project, circular dependencies arise.

Is the best practice really to put the user login logic in the business layer?

I'm just interested in common practice patterns or your reasoning for having it in the UI layer vs the Business layer or vice versa or something I haven't thought of.

Thanks!

Comment: The security/login *logic* should reside in the domain (business) layer; the ui component to *visualize* the login process is an implementation detail of the ui layer.

Comment: And you say that your business layer doesn't care if a user is logged on. I find that strange, how are you ever going to implement any authentication or authorization that way? I would say knowing which user is logged on is an essential part of applying any security, which is defined by *busines rules*, which should be defined in the domain/business layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most enterprise level applications I have seen implement some form of Security layer which is usually independent and may contain roles, permissions, and login methods. This is usually the security guard that returns whether or not a user has access to a specified resource. This Security layer will usually also have its own data access layer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think this is the correct answer. It makes perfect sense to abstract security away into its own library. You get the benefits of not coupling any layers together, and if the project is ported to another platform within the company, that platform should already support the security library. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of how I've laid out security for an application.

1. User credentials passed in. The presenter forwards credentials to security layer
2. The security layer maintains its own communication with a DAL. Could be separate from the rest of the B/L.
3. DAL returns data to security which is tokenized or given a security key.
4. Security passes the token or security key back to the presenter/controller for the application
5. Application wraps or includes the token or security key with all transactions.

The B/L here can then validate the token/key with Security before processing any transaction.
[image: Security Sample]

My references basically lay out like so:
[image: Domain References]